# Get values from CSS span element with constantly changing values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website that seems to use different values each time a particular span element appears. For example, the first few times the span element appears, it could be:

```
<span title="PM XX">PM XX</span>
<span title="Star Charterist">Star Charterist</span>
<span title="Elephant Trainer">Elephant Trainer</span>
```

I have tried the following, but I keep getting either empty lists:

```
site = BeautifulSoup(link.text, "html.parser")

jobs_a = site.find_all("span title")
```

or

```
jobs_a = site.find_all("span", attrs="title")
```

or

```
jobs_a = site.find_all("span", attrs="title*")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using a CSS selector.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<span title="PM XX">PM XX</span>
<span title="Star Charterist">Star Charterist</span>
<span title="Elephant Trainer">Elephant Trainer</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for s in soup.select('span[title]'):
    print(f"{s.text=}\t{s.attrs['title']=}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. One minor change got it working: 1) dropping the "=" signs removed the errors remove a syntax error.

Comment: @Clauric you can access it directly using `s['title']`

Comment: You must be using an older version of python then if the `=` signs are giving you errors.

Comment: BTW, the `=` in f-strings works in python >=3.8. Syntax error in python <=3.7.